# Ways to update progress bar

Tags: nsis

I want to control progressbar in my nsis installer. Actually I'm using [ThreadTimer](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/ThreadTimer_plug-in) plugin but I've got big problem with it. ThreadTimer runs function every 10 seconds to update progress bar (increace progress bar value by 1%). The problem is that it crashes stack (as I can see ThreadTimer is using the same stack as NSIS). `Crashes stack` means that when I want to get value from the stack the value is wrong because of ThreadTimer function action. Any ideas? Maybe there are some other ways to update progress bar?

Those are functions/macros which should update progress bar. Macro `StartProgressBarIntervalUpdate` starts updating progress bar, macro `StopProgressBarIntervalUpdate` stops doping it.

```
Var /GLOBAL ProgressBarPosition
Var /GLOBAL ProgressBarParentWindow
Var /GLOBAL ProgressBarItem

Function InitProgressBar
    StrCpy $ProgressBarPosition "0"
    FindWindow $ProgressBarParentWindow "#32770" "" $HWNDPARENT
    GetDlgItem $ProgressBarItem $ProgressBarParentWindow 1004
FunctionEnd

Function UpdateProgressBarTimer
    ${If} $ProgressBarPosition >= 30000 ; 100% * 300
        StrCpy $ProgressBarPosition "0"
    ${Endif}
    IntOp $ProgressBarPosition $ProgressBarPosition + 300
    SendMessage $ProgressBarItem ${PBM_SETPOS} $ProgressBarPosition 0
FunctionEnd

!define StartProgressBarIntervalUpdate "!insertmacro StartProgressBarIntervalUpdate"
!macro StartProgressBarIntervalUpdate
    Call InitProgressBar
    GetFunctionAddress $UpdateProgressBarTimerFunctionAddress UpdateProgressBarTimer
    ThreadTimer::Start /NOUNLOAD 20 -1 $UpdateProgressBarTimerFunctionAddress
    Sleep 1000
!macroend

!define StopProgressBarIntervalUpdate "!insertmacro StopProgressBarIntervalUpdate"
!macro StopProgressBarIntervalUpdate
    ThreadTimer::Stop $UpdateProgressBarTimerFunctionAddress
    Sleep 15000
!macroend
```

Here are sections which uses progressbar

```
Var /GLOBAL UpdateProgressBarTimerFunctionAddress
Section BeforeMoveData SEC01
    ${StartProgressBarIntervalUpdate}

    Call core.UnpackExeData
SectionEnd

Section OnMoveData SEC02    
    Call InstallFiles
    Call InstallRegistry
    Call InstallShortcuts

    ${StopProgressBarIntervalUpdate}

    ...

SectionEnd
```

Comment: Could you post some code to show how you call the timer and use it? You might have a problem in you stack usage.

Comment: Ar first eye sight, I noticed nothing suspicious with stack, but to be sure, you could use the [DumpState plugin](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/DumpState_plug-in) to display the stack state at the begining and end of the callbacks, associated with a high value for the timer refresh to check is the stack is actually corrupted.

Comment: I've used this plugin but it shows me wrong values. I use NSIS Unicode and maybe this is why dumpstate4 shows wrong values.

Comment: That plugin does not push to the stack in the timer callback...